# Content Transitions on Top of Shared Elements in android

Tags: android, android-transitions, shared-element-transition, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I am trying my hands with SharedElements and Content Transitions in Android. I was trying to combine Content Transitions and Shared Elements and create a particular animation, however I have encountered a problem. After the transition on Shared Elements (ImageView) end, I am using content Transitions to animate Text View into position using Slide Transition. However when the textViews are sliding from Bottom to their position on the top of image View, the text goes beneath the ImageView (Shared Element) and later just appears on the top of the ImageView. Is there a way to do this right?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am sharing a short code here with some screenshots which explain this:

Activity_A.java

```
package com.example.mehulp.sharedelementsviewheirarchy;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;


public class Activity_a extends Activity {
ImageView imageView_a;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_activity_a);

    imageView_a = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView_a);
    imageView_a.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            imageClickListener();
        }
    });
}

private void imageClickListener() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Activity_a.this, Activity_b.class);
    startActivity(intent, ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView_a, imageView_a.getTransitionName()).toBundle());
}
}
```

activity_a.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgView_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="fImage"
        android:padding="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/female_result"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/imgView_a">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myName_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="MyName: Lorem Ipsum Ipsum"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myAge_a"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Age: abc years, xyz months, pqr days"
            android:padding="10dp"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Activity_B.java

```
package com.example.mehulp.sharedelementsviewheirarchy;

import java.util.List;

public class Activity_b extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_b);

    setEnterSharedElementCallback(new SharedElementCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSharedElementStart(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {

            TransitionSet transitionSet = new TransitionSet();
            transitionSet.setDuration(3000);

            Slide slideFromBottom = new Slide(Gravity.BOTTOM);
            slideFromBottom.addTarget(R.id.myAge_b);
            slideFromBottom.addTarget(R.id.myName_b);

            transitionSet.addTransition(slideFromBottom);
            getWindow().setEnterTransition(transitionSet);

            super.onSharedElementStart(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots);
        }

        @Override
        public void onSharedElementEnd(List<String> sharedElementNames, List<View> sharedElements, List<View> sharedElementSnapshots) {
            super.onSharedElementEnd(sharedElementNames, sharedElements, sharedElementSnapshots);
        }
    });
}}
```

activity_b.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:transitionName="fImage"
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/female_result"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_b"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myName_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="MyName: Lorem Ipsum Ipsum"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/myAge_b"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="My Age: abc years, xyz months, pqr days"
        android:padding="10dp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I've tried the only answer below, but that just adds other unwanted side effects.

Comment: I have found not solution to this. Also, the solution by Sigitas below does not work. The transition will kind of be clipped by its parent.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. Maybe it's not possible.

Answer (score 6):

i have had same problem added

```
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementsUseOverlay">false</item>
```

to the animated activity theme

Comment: this is solved my problem , but when transition process i am seeing weird padding.

Answer (score 0):

I kindof found a solution to a similar problem, here: [Android shared view transition combined with fade transition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32256168/android-shared-view-transition-combined-with-fade-transition/32356093#32356093)

In short, I disabled overlay for shared elements, as suggested above. Then i removed the background on the Activity (by using a transparent theme). See my answer, maybe it would have helped you (I assume this you have moved on by now).